# Ruby on Rails: undefined method "comments" for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an app with users where they each have set of microposts displayed on their pages. I am trying to add comments to these microposts. Every time I visit localhost:3000/users/(user_id_#)

I get this error: undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

This error only comes when the user has microposts to show. Otherwise it just shows their blank page. The error comes from this view for app/views/users/show.html.erb This view renders this partial, where the error occurs in line 13.

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
      <b>Commenter:</b>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Comment:</b>
      <%= comment.body %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
  <%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Here is my comment.rb file

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost
  attr_accessible :body, :user_id

end
```

and my micropost.rb file

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

and my comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
  end

end
```

and finally my microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end


  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])
  end

  def show

    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])


  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end


    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
        @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment])
        redirect_to micropost_path(@micropost)
      end

    end
```

also here is the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = @user.microposts.first
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

from the error it sounds like the @micropost isnt being initialized in the microposts_controller.rb file under def show. but I think it is? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

also here is app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a UsersController? By convention, I would expect users/(user_id_#) to be routed there.

Comment: i just added the users_controller.rb. Should I somehow define the comments method in this under def show? how should I write it? Would a line like @comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment]) work?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is here in your partial:

```
<% @micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

I am assuming that you are iterating over *@microposts* and passing each micro post to your partial as *micropost*. In the above line you are using the instance variable *@micropost* when you should be using the local *micropost*.

Update: and also here:

```
<%= form_for([@micropost, @micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %> –
```

Comment: hmm I changed that @micropost to just micropost and got the same error. any other ideas?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to do similarly here: <%= form_for([@micropost, @micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %> –

Comment: ok I took the @ off of both of those as well and then added @comment=Comment.new under def show in the users controller. Now it tells me SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.micropost_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."micropost_id" = 1

Comment: yeah. Doesnt taking away the @ make the browser treat comments as a column in the table microposts? Is this what its supposed to do?

Comment: I assume *micropost* is a reference to an instance of Micropost. Thus *micropost.comments* refers to the has_many association to the Comment class.

Comment: that is correct. If you look at Duong Thang's answer below, he offers a solution that seems to at least change what the error is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change this `@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])` into this `@micropost = @user.microposts.first` and see if it works ? 
I think since the partial is rendered in the context of users#show that why @micropost is nil.

This is not an answer, I just want to comment but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: interesting. after doing this and everything in rich drummonds answer above it seems to encounter a new error in line 16 instead of 13. This is the error : 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path. Im not sure if a different error means that the first one was fixed

Comment: Why did you add the `@comment = Comement.new` ? Now, change your users#show back and don't add the `@comment`. That means: `def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end` Read [Rendering partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) section 3.4.5 for more info.

Comment: I just changed it back but it didnt seem to help. I got the exact same error

Comment: Did you check whether `@microposts =@user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])` return nil or not ? If not, you can add a debugger after this line to inspect it.